Getting different results using same Random Forest model with same predictors
I am trying to use a Random Forest model in R for regression using the randomForest package, and I'm having an issue in which using the predict function with an already fitted model yields different results on a test set and on the same observations of a subset of the same set. I do have a handful of categorical and numerical predictors.
I was not able to reproduce this issue with common data, but I'll put an example just to illustrate the structure of my analysis.
library(randomForest)

library(dplyr)

iris <- iris

library(caret)

# Separate into test and train

trainIndex <- createDataPartition(iris$Species, p = .8, list = FALSE)

train <- iris[ trainIndex,]

test <- iris[-trainIndex,]

# Train the model

RF_model <- randomForest(Sepal.Width ~ ., data = train)

# Make predictions on the test set

predictions <- predict(RF_model, test)

# Make predictions with the same model on the first observation of the test set only 

prediction_first_obs <- predict(RF_model, test %>% slice(1))

As I mentioned, on this iris example, it behaves as expected and the prediction of the subset is the same as for the first observation of the test set.
However, with the data I'm working this is not working, and depending on the subset it gives different results for the same observation (identical predictors) with the same model.
I'm pretty new to these models, I thought the predict function worked by viewing each observation independently, which is what I need, cause I'm building a prediction tool, and I wanted to know if anyone has faced something similar, and what can I do to circumvent this issue.
Thank you.
